# Backbone model urlRoot share the middle part of api

Tags: backbone.js

I want to fetch an api and the format is like `apps/[:id]/result`.

For most of the example or [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-urlRoot) about setting the urlRoot is based on having the same root url.

But my problem is the api share the same root and the end of the api name.

I try to use below code, but it doesn't work.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/apps"
})

var model = new Model({id: 123123 + "/content"]}) //123123 just fake id
```

Does it any way to change only the `middle` of the id?

Or in this situation, use `urlRoot` is inappropriate?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing, really. If you're aiming to write a rest api, then you're doing it wrong, because the url is meant to identify the resource, not the representation of the resource (which is what that 'content' bit really is). Even if you're not trying to create a rest api you're confusing concepts: the id you have provided isn't an id, it's a url -- you should really keep the id as the id, and override the model's fetch method to append the "/content" path element when retrieving the model's data from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone's persistence methods, which are built around `url` and `urlRoot`, are designed for RESTful persistence. Each method is designed to communicate with a server using well-defined semantics (`GET /path` means list, PUT `/path/:id` means update, etc).

Chaning the meaning of `id` is a bad idea because you depart break those semantics, meaning that a) your model will not work with create, update or delete REST operations, and b) your code will become difficult to understand since `id` will no longer be a descriptive variable name. Backbone uses `id` frequently in Models and Collections, so it would be a very bad idea to change its meaning.

If you are not using a REST API, or you have a particular operation that does not fit that paradigm (like searching), it is best to implement your own methods to make custom HTTP requests.

In your case, something like this should work as you expect:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "/apps",
  fetchResult: function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: this.url() + '/result'
    }).then(function(response) {
       // do something with response
       // return response, or the result of your processing,
       //  for downstream promise handlers
       return response;
    }, function() {
      console.error('fetchResult failed');
    })
  },

})
```

With this approach the RESTful URLs work as designed and you don't lose the semantics of `id`.